# Laravel Query Builder max function and relationships

Tags: laravel

this code

```
$maxsub =  Invoice::with(['userinvoicesubaccount'])->where([['person_id',$id]])->get();

 @foreach($maxsub as $max)
         {{$max->userinvoicesubaccount->subaccount_name}}   </font></div>
 @endforeach
```

Get me all subaccount's names related to my list of Invoices with a predefined ID.

What i need is to get the only subaccount name related to my list of invoices **with the highest amount** *(that existe in my invoice table)* with a predefined ID.

Any help ? thank you

Comment: Can you post your model code to see the relationship definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the invoice with the highest amount like so:

```
$maxInvoice = Invoice::with('userinvoicesubaccount')->where('person_id',$id)
              ->orderBy('amount', 'desc')->first();
```

Then get the related sub accounts for that invoice like so:

```
$maxInvoice->userinvoicesubaccount
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a subquery to your `with` function.

```
$invoices =  Invoice::with(['userinvoicesubaccount' => function($query) {
    $query->max('amount');  // Max function gives you highest value of a given column
}])
->where([['person_id', $id]])
->get();

 @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
         // You will still need to call first because you will have a collection
         {{$invoice->first()->userinvoicesubaccount->subaccount_name}}   </font></div>
 @endforeach
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: The OP mentioned that the amount column exists in the invoice table and not the sub account table

Comment: Thank you sir for ur interest